# Excel VBA Dictionary item concatenate

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, concatenation

i need help with dictionary understanding so im trying with something simple. I have code that search and delete duplicate value.

I store dict Key as People and item as ID's. Idea is to loop to cell range with data, find duplicate values delete them but concatenate Item(ID's).

How can i get item from Dictionary to range cell with ID's and concatenate values? I wolud appreciate and help, link, tutorial, suggestion

Code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DictionaryTest()
    
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim People As String
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim item As Variant
    
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Debug.Print rowCount
    
    Do While rowCount > 1
    
        People = Sheet2.Cells(rowCount, "E").Value
        ID = Sheet2.Cells(rowCount, "D").Value
        
        If dict.Exists(People) Then
            'Sheet2.Rows(rowCount).EntireRow.Delete
            
        Else
            dict.Add People, ID
        End If
        
        rowCount = rowCount - 1
        
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: @TimWilliams It's been a day. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing the ID value in the dictionary, you can reference the ID cell and concatenate the values there.

```
Dim idCell As Range, r As Long    
'...
'...
For r = rowCount to 2 Step - 1

    People = Sheet2.Cells(rowCount, "E").Value
    Set idCell = Sheet2.Cells(rowCount, "D")
    
    If dict.Exists(People) Then
        With dict(People) '<< first id cell... 
            .Value = .Value & ";" & IdCell.Value 
        End With
        Sheet2.Rows(rowCount).EntireRow.Delete 'get id *before* delete ;-)
    Else
        dict.Add People, idCell 'reference first ID cell (the cell
                                '  itself, not the cell value)
    End If

 Next r
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. Im trying to figure it our your code. What it do is delete last row that's not duplicate but not sure about .Value function without range cell reference but i see that it can concatenate ID number

Comment: Do you have some link tutorials? Im not really in copy-paste code I would like to learn and understand it

Comment: The range reference is `dict(People)` ( a reference to that cell is stored as the dictionary value associated with the key `People`)  and the `.Value` is linked to that by the `With` block.  Sorry I don't have any references which address that specifically: the general docs for the Dictionary object should be applicable though.

Comment: Yes im working all day to adjust your code to my needs. Its very close what i need but it's more understandable now i get it to work. I really appreciate your help. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works for you.

```
Sub RemDupVal()
        
    Dim t As Range, x As Range, z As Range
        
       Set x = Range("A2:A7") 'ID
       Set z = Range("B2:B7") 'Item
       Set t = Cells(2, Cells(1, 16383).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1).Resize(x.Rows.Count)
        
        t = x.Parent.Evaluate(x.Address & "&" & z.Address) 'assuming evaluate character limit is met
        Union(x, t).Select
        selection.RemoveDuplicates t.Column, xlNo
        t.ClearContents: Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Karan! This code dont work for me beacose i already adjusting my code to work with dictionary function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this code and update it a bit. I see that I Immediate window Items from duplicate dictionary are concatenate so code work exactly what I want but I don't know how I can get that value concatenate in cells. In dictionary keys are People and Item are ID

This is best result I have in many code testing.

[image: How it should look like]

```
Sub DictTest()

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rowsCount As Long
Dim People As String, id As Integer


Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

rowsCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
People = Sheet2.Cells(rowsCount, "D").Value

    Do While rowsCount > 1
        People = Sheet2.Cells(rowsCount, "D").Value
        id = Sheet2.Cells(rowsCount, "C")
        
            'if duplicate value is found then concatenate Item value
            If dict.Exists(People) Then
                dict(People) = dict(People) & "," & " " & id
               
                Debug.Print dict(People) '-> in immediate window shows concatenate Item values
                                        
                Sheet2.Rows(rowsCount).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                dict.Add People, id
            End If
            
    rowsCount = rowsCount - 1
    
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have another question, please *create a new post* - do not add it as an answer to your original question.

Comment: My bad. Posted new post. Thanks!